# Page numbering in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word file. I changed from that file two middle pages from portait to landscape in order to be more visible. However that transforamtion change the page numbering of the file. In order to perform that transformation I use breaks -> new page thus my file is as I have got 3 different files. For the first M portrati pages the numbering is 1... to N and the next two landscape pages 1, 2 and then the final M portrait pages 1 ... M. How can I merge the numbering in order to be continuous of all those "files".

Answer (score 4):

Check that "**Continue from previous section**" is actually set in the *Insert > Headers and Footers > Page Number > Format Page Numbers* dialogue (valid for Word 2010 at least), for all sections of the document.